# Python import scheme

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a python library, where some files depend on other files, for example:

I have folder structure:

```
../libname
../libname/core.py
../libname/supplementary1.py
../libname/supplementary2.py
../libname/__init__.py
```

where libname is where I import from.

the core.py file begins with:

```
import supplementary1
import supplementary2
```

...some code...

and this works fine, if I test it in the **main** of the core.py

Let's say I want to use libname as library in my project. My folder structure is then:

```
./libname
./main.py
```

where main.py calls functions from core.py, which in fact need functions from supplementary1 and supplementary2.

Currently, it throws me an error, saying there is no supplementary1, if I try (in main.py)

```
from core.py import function1
```

My question is, how do I import files from my library then? I mean one option would be to copy all the code from e.g. supplementary1 to the core.py, but I wish to maintain my code elegantly separated, if possible.

So in other words, how does one import a file, which already imports some files from a local library?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `import ...` and `from ... import ...` you need to write not the filename, but module name. Instead of `core.py` you should say `libname.core`, meaning "module `core`, from package `libname`" (`libname` will be [searched in all module paths](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), that normally includes the directory of the script you've started, i.e. where your `main.py` is).

tl;dr: a simple answer to your question is to write `from libname.core import function1` instead.

Also, I'd suggest to use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) and instead of `import supplementary1` write `from . import supplementary1` - here, `from .` means "from the current package - where this file (module) resides in".

Consider reading [Python documentation on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) - there are a lot of examples and explanations there.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it well for me.